# DOM Based Open redirection

Tags: javascript, dom, xss

I am able to confirm that DOM type of open direction is possible here.. But not able to make the POC work.

Below is the javascript code:

```js
 if (window == window.top) {
          var query = location.search.replace(/(theme_id|_sc|token)=[\w\-%]*&?/ig, '');
          query += (query.length === 1 || query[query.length - 1] === '&' ? '' : '&') + 'nopreview';
          window.location = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + query;
        }
```

value from location.search is passing to window.location.

and my URL is of type

> https://example.com/?theme_id=1212&_sc=test&token=1232

How, I make it work for DOM based openredirection ?

Comment: I don't think you can. It's using `location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + query` before the data you control, so you are limited to the same protocol, hostname and pathname